# Calculating carbon sequestration on the percentage of tree cover

Tags: co2, forest, carbon

What variables are necessary to calculate carbon sequestration on densely population tree cover over a large spatial range?

I wish to work on a project that has been proposed to me and my team at work. We are currently at the stage of determining it's possibility given that we are only junior analysts, and not earth scientists, though some of us have a background in environmental/earth science.

As far as I am aware, the calculation required for carbon sequestration of trees requires the trees breast height, age,biomas below and above ground and soil carbon.

Given that I am able to collect data on Tree cover percentage of a large spatial range say Europe from the MODIS landsat, would it be possible to calculate carbon sequestration from this alone?

Link: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod44bv006/

If I am to collect soil biomass at some depth how would this contribute to the dataset in calculating carbon sequestration?

I am happy to receive some articles that can help me formulate this together or other datasets that would suit my purpose. Otherwise, please let me know if this is not possible given the data provided.